# Postgres search in JSONB

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-10

The custom_fields field in a row looks like that:

```
[
   {
      "value":"Test Name",
      "display_name":"Name",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "person-name"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"",
      "display_name":"Telefonnummer",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "phone"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"test@test.net",
      "display_name":"E-Mail",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "e-mail"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"Sonnberg 170",
      "display_name":"Adresse",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "address"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"1/",
      "display_name":"Personen Anzahl",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "person-number-info"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"",
      "display_name":"Notiz",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "trace"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"A la Carte",
      "display_name":"Typ",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "price-type"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"Montag, 11. Mai 2020 19:30",
      "display_name":"Anreise",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "arrival"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"Montag, 11. Mai 2020 20:30",
      "display_name":"Abreise",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "departure"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"2020-05-11 19:30",
      "display_name":"Ankunft bei Reservierung",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "arrival",
         "hidden"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"2020-05-11 20:30",
      "display_name":"Abfahrt bei Reservierung",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "departure",
         "hidden"
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to query this DB by searching with a searchTerm the value of the `value` key of the objects including `servicio_tags":["person-name"]` or `servicio_tags":["full-name"]`.

So if the searchTerm is `a` it should give me back this row because the object in the JSON

```
{
      "value":"Anton Hoerl Jun.",
      "display_name":"Name",
      "servicio_tags":[
      "person-name"
      ]
},
```

fulfills this criteria.

My try:

```
const fullNameString = '%{"value": "' + searchTerm + '", "display_name": "Name", "servicio_tags": ["full-name"]}%';
const personNameString = '%{"value": "' + searchTerm + '", "display_name": "Name",
"servicio_tags": ["person-name"]}%';

const result = await this.db.query(
`SELECT * 
FROM guest_group
AND custom_fields::text like $2
OR custom_fields::text like $3 LIMIT 5`, [customerId, fullNameString, personNameString]);
```

This query does not give me the desired result, because it only returns rows if the seachTerm is exactly like the value of the key value. I want that it returns the row also if the value of the value key only contains the searchTerm.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unnest the array and compare the individual values:

```
select g.*
from guest_group g
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(g.custom_fields) as f(element)
              where f.element ->> 'value' ilike 'a%');
```

Note that I used `ilike` to do a case insensitive comparison.